# C# как HTTP серверу вернуть ответ от Background Worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, httplistener

HttpListener принимает GET запрос

```
if (GET["makereport"] != null){
    
}
```

есть BackgroundWorker который должен вернуть строку

```
public void makeReport_bg(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
    //тут долгие расчеты и формирование строки для ответа
    string result="result";
}

void makeReport_completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e){
    
}

response.ContentType = "text/html";
response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
Stream output = response.OutputStream;
output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
output.Close();
```

как передать эту строку в response?

Comment: Почему `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Пусть старичок `BackgroundWorker` покоится с миром. Добро пожаловать в [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). А вообще, ваш код слишком абстрактный, сложно понять, где что находится, что откуда запускается, и что куда передать. Выкладывайте всю длинную простыню, так будет легче разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Если нельзя переписать генератор отчета под async/await, используйте `Parallel.Invoke`, это проще и нагляднее чем `BackgroundWorker`. В качесте `Action` используйте лямбда-функцию, из которой и верните результат прямо в локальную переменную в коде обработки HTTP запроса.

Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netcore-3.1